# File data binding with column names

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-binding, file-handling

I have files with hundreds and thousands rows of data but they are without any column.
I am trying to go to every file and make them row by row and store them in list after that I want to assign values by columns. But here I am confused what to do because values are around 60 in every row and some extra columns with value assigned and they should be added in every row. 
**Code so for**:

```
import re
import glob
filenames = glob.glob("/home/ashfaque/Desktop/filetocsvsample/inputfiles/*.txt")
columns = []
with open("/home/ashfaque/Downloads/coulmn names.txt",encoding = "ISO-8859-1") as f:
    file_data = f.read()
    lines = file_data.splitlines()
    for l in lines:
        columns.append(l.rstrip())

total = {}
for name in filenames:
    modified_data = []
    with open(name,encoding = "ISO-8859-1") as f:
        file_data = f.read()
        lines = file_data.splitlines()
        for l in lines:
            if len(l) >= 1:
                modified_data.append(re.split(': |,',l))
    rows = []
    i = len(modified_data)
    x = 0
    while i > 60:
        r = lines[x:x+59]
        x = x + 60
        i = i - 60
        rows.append(r)
    z = len(modified_data)
    while z >= 60:
        z = z - 60
    if z > 1:
        last_columns = modified_data[-z:]
    x = []
    for l in last_columns:
        if len(l) > 1:
            del l[0]
            x.append(l)
        elif len(l) == 1:
            x.append(l)
    for row in rows:
        for vl in x:
            row.append(vl)
    for r in rows:
        for i in range(0,len(r)):
            if len(r) >= 60:
                total.setdefault(columns[i],[]).append(r[i])
```

In other script I have separated both row with 60 values and last 5 to 15 columns which should be added with row are separate but again I am confused how to bind all the data.
Data Should look like this after binding.
[outputdata.xlsx](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oblX7Ddfu2KacF_w-BcxylpHHQ9bI32l/view?usp=sharing)
Data Input file:
[inputdata.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZYNxyD_zU2T-L8izFgCMK88akLLpwunS/view?usp=sharing)

What Am I missing here? any tool ?

Comment: To confirm, your input file is filled with one piece of data per line, and multiple lines make up a row of data?  Also, what version of python are you using?

Comment: 60 lines per row. You can see the serial no after 60 lines. 0001/0002/0003.

Comment: One more thing, do you want all the data in memory, or do you want it in a file, like the xlsx you posted?

Comment: xlsx would be great.

Comment: If data is saved in pandas dataframe / dict is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your issue can be resolved by taking the input file and turning it into a CSV file which you can then import into whatever program you like.

I wrote a small generator that would read a file a line at a time and return a row after a certain number of lines, in this case 60.  In that generator, you can make whatever modifications to the data as you need.

Then with each generated row, I write it directly to the csv.  This should keep the memory requirements for this process pretty low.

I didn't understand what you were doing with the regex split, but it would be simple enough to add it to the generator.

```
import csv

OUTPUT_FILE = "/home/ashfaque/Desktop/File handling/outputfile.csv"
INPUT_FILE = "/home/ashfaque/Desktop/File handling/inputfile.txt"


# This is a generator that will pull only num number of items into
# memory at a time, before it yields the row.
def get_rows(path, num):
    row = []
    with open(path, "r", encoding="ISO-8859-1") as f:
        for n, l in enumerate(f):
            # apply whatever transformations that you need to here.
            row.append(l.rstrip())
            if (n + 1) % num == 0:
                # if rows need padding then do it here.
                yield row
                row = []


with open(OUTPUT_FILE, "w") as output:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(output)
    for r in get_rows(INPUT_FILE, 60):
        csv_writer.writerow(r)
```

Comment: I have around 71 Columns names. I will add link in question.
I want to read every file and make 60 lines per row and after that I have to read 11 lines some files may have 5 or 8 or 10. Last lines on every file are columns with valued I want to assign last lines to every row data. If try to look in input file you will find last lines different from other lines. that lines should be assign to every row data.
Now if we look in output file we see it has 71 columns with names and we have data according to column.

Comment: ok, so you have a single input file with two sections.  The first section is the individual row data (60 lines makes a row). The second section is an arbitrary number(this file is 11, but it could be 5,8 or 10) of meta data associated with the file, which you want to associate with each row for that file, correct?

Comment: yes, correct.
Second section data should be bind with their respective column.

Comment: I have updated the code but I am missing the second section here last column data are not accurate.